# gradle: Java API for JSON Processing (JSR 374)

Tags: java, json, maven, gradle, javax.json

How are the dependencies for JSON Processing, [JSR 374](https://javaee.github.io/jsonp/), handled from gradle?  Working examples would be greatly appreciated.

**context:  below is what I have with *maven*; looking to migrate this to *gradle.***

build is ok, even if there are duplicates:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloJsonMaven$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloJsonMaven$ mvn clean package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building HelloJsonMaven 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ HelloJsonMaven ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/HelloJsonMaven/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ HelloJsonMaven ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ HelloJsonMaven ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/HelloJsonMaven/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ HelloJsonMaven ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/HelloJsonMaven/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ HelloJsonMaven ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ HelloJsonMaven ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ HelloJsonMaven ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/HelloJsonMaven/target/HelloJsonMaven-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:3.1.0:shade (default) @ HelloJsonMaven ---
[INFO] Including javax.json:javax.json-api:jar:1.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.glassfish:javax.json:jar:1.0.4 in the shaded jar.
[WARNING] Discovered module-info.class. Shading will break its strong encapsulation.
[WARNING] javax.json-1.0.4.jar, javax.json-api-1.1.jar define 25 overlapping classes: 
[WARNING]   - javax.json.stream.JsonParser
[WARNING]   - javax.json.stream.JsonParserFactory
[WARNING]   - javax.json.JsonString
[WARNING]   - javax.json.JsonValue
[WARNING]   - javax.json.stream.JsonLocation
[WARNING]   - javax.json.Json
[WARNING]   - javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException
[WARNING]   - javax.json.stream.JsonParser$Event
[WARNING]   - javax.json.JsonWriter
[WARNING]   - javax.json.JsonValue$ValueType
[WARNING]   - 15 more...
[WARNING] maven-shade-plugin has detected that some class files are
[WARNING] present in two or more JARs. When this happens, only one
[WARNING] single version of the class is copied to the uber jar.
[WARNING] Usually this is not harmful and you can skip these warnings,
[WARNING] otherwise try to manually exclude artifacts based on
[WARNING] mvn dependency:tree -Ddetail=true and the above output.
[WARNING] See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/
[INFO] Replacing original artifact with shaded artifact.
[INFO] Replacing /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/HelloJsonMaven/target/HelloJsonMaven-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar with /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/HelloJsonMaven/target/HelloJsonMaven-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar
[INFO] Dependency-reduced POM written at: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/HelloJsonMaven/dependency-reduced-pom.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.616 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-10-21T12:15:07-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/61M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloJsonMaven$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloJsonMaven$
```

and the `JAR` actually runs:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloJsonMaven$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloJsonMaven$ java -jar target/HelloJsonMaven-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
Oct 21, 2017 12:15:19 PM net.bounceme.dur.hello_json_maven.Main props
INFO: {foo=bar}
Oct 21, 2017 12:15:20 PM net.bounceme.dur.hello_json_maven.JsonOperations createJsonObject
INFO: creating..
Oct 21, 2017 12:15:20 PM net.bounceme.dur.hello_json_maven.Main json
INFO: {"name":"Falco","age":3,"biteable":false}
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloJsonMaven$
```

sample code:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.hello_json_maven;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonObject;

public class JsonOperations {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(JsonOperations.class.getName());

    public void loadJsonFromFile(String jsonFileName) {
        log.info(jsonFileName);
    }

    public JsonObject createJsonObject() {
        // Create Json and serialize
        log.info("creating..");
        JsonObject json = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                .add("name", "Falco")
                .add("age", BigDecimal.valueOf(3))
                .add("biteable", Boolean.FALSE).build();
        String result = json.toString();
        log.fine(json.toString());
        return json;
    }

}
```

Having been down this road [before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45767658/262852), seems prudent to ask before going too far down any false paths.

pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>net.bounceme.dur</groupId>
    <artifactId>HelloJsonMaven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>net.bounceme.dur.hello_json_maven.Main</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.json/javax.json-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: What have you tried? It is standard on Stack Overflow to at least make an effort and then ask questions about that code.

Comment: One tip is to examine the doc for the 'jar' plugin or especially the 'application' plugin. It is quite straight-forward from there.

Comment: I knew there was something wonky, just couldn't remember what the problem was:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/46873255/262852  so this question is dead. close. too broad.