# netbeans: nothing to fix in import statements. Yet, import is required. (Gradle)

Tags: gradle, netbeans, ide, dependencies, packaging

When a crucial import statement is commented out Netbeans reports "nothing to fix in import statement":

[image: nothing to fix in import statements]

Putting the import back in, the project builds and runs fine:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloJsonGradle$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloJsonGradle$ gradle clean shadowJar

> Task :shadowJar
The SimpleWorkResult type has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use WorkResults.didWork() instead.


BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloJsonGradle$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloJsonGradle$ java -jar build/libs/JsonShadowJar.jar 
Oct 22, 2017 3:41:58 AM net.bounceme.dur.json_gradle.Main props
INFO: {foo=bar}
Oct 22, 2017 3:41:58 AM net.bounceme.dur.json_gradle.JsonOperations createJsonObject
INFO: creating..
Oct 22, 2017 3:41:58 AM net.bounceme.dur.json_gradle.Main json
INFO: {"name":"Falco","age":3,"biteable":false}
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloJsonGradle$
```

simple build file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.gradle.build-scan' version '1.8' 
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '2.0.1'
}

buildScan {
    licenseAgreementUrl = 'https://gradle.com/terms-of-service'
    licenseAgree = 'yes'
    //publishAlways()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.9
targetCompatibility = 1.9

mainClassName = 'net.bounceme.dur.json_gradle.Main'

shadowJar {
    baseName = 'JsonShadowJar'
    classifier = null
    version = null
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

configurations {
    provided
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'javax.json', name: 'javax.json-api', version: '1.1'
    compile group: 'org.glassfish', name: 'javax.json', version: '1.0.4'
}
```

yet, netbeans complains that the "package javax.json does not exist":

[image: package javax.json does not exist]

and that "the type of create JsonObject is erroneous":

[image: the type of create jsonobject is erroneous]

The problem isn't with the build file, `build.gradle`, nor with the source code itself.  Some sort of usage with Netbeans where the IDE isn't picking up that the package is needed and available:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloJsonGradle$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloJsonGradle$ jar -tf build/libs/JsonShadowJar.jar 
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
net/
net/bounceme/
net/bounceme/dur/
net/bounceme/dur/json_gradle/
net/bounceme/dur/json_gradle/Main.class
net/bounceme/dur/json_gradle/PropertiesUtils.class
net/bounceme/dur/json_gradle/JsonOperations.class
person.json
properties.properties
connection.properties
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/javax.json/
META-INF/maven/javax.json/javax.json-api/
META-INF/maven/javax.json/javax.json-api/pom.properties
META-INF/maven/javax.json/javax.json-api/pom.xml
javax/
javax/json/
javax/json/Json.class
javax/json/JsonArray.class
javax/json/JsonArrayBuilder.class
javax/json/JsonBuilderFactory.class
javax/json/JsonException.class
javax/json/JsonMergePatch.class
javax/json/JsonNumber.class
javax/json/JsonObject.class
```

The `JsonObject` is right there in the `Shadowjar`.

Comment: Even after reloading the project in netbeans it doesn't work?

Comment: @Hillkorn wow, thanks so much.  go ahead and make that answer for saving me from the eclipse GUI.